# What happen when a CompletableFuture never completed?

Tags: java

What happen when a CompletableFuture never completed? Does it cost a memory leak? or worse does it used up a thread from the thread pool?

If it does happen what can we do to clean these incompleted futures up?

To clarify let say I have a function like the following, would this cause any leaks or consume a thread within the pool while executing the task?

```
public void foo()
{
   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::functionNeverComplete, pool)
       .whenComplete((r,e) -> logger.info("done {}",r,e));
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it complete?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. A `CompletableFuture` is unrelated to any threads. It behaves like any other object. It'll get GC'ed when it is deemed unreachable.

Comment: What does the javadoc of `supplyAsync` say?

Comment: Must be something I missed because according to the api, it didn't really say anything https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-

Answer (score 0):

Well what do you think? If you have a thread running an infinite loop, then you've got one thread that's not being used for anything else. Unless you explicitly `cancel()` the processing, nothing will stop it automatically.

So the question is: why would you run an infinitely long task as a `CompletableFuture`?

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely long task was spawning a runtime to execute a command and capture the resulting output. It turns out the stuck behavior is attributed to the spawned process trying to wait for lock that was orphan (the process that owns it died).

After the lock has been cleaned the code start to work. I guess in retrospect the answer should be obvious as @Kayaman suggested.